# How do I run kd inside a Windows docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

How do I run `KD.exe` inside a windows docker container? Simply running `kd.exe` did not help, as com ports are not present inside docker.

Has anyone dealt with this same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not possible because of the missing port.